# How to put legend outside of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to fit my legend outside of my plot. I have tried using the function ax1.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),
ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
which I saw suggested on another forum but I get the error: "No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument."

Here is the code I am using for the plot:

```
x = ['25%', '50%', '75%', '100%','Baseline']
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

Manure = np.array([total_manure_CO2e_mtonnes_25, total_manure_CO2e_mtonnes_50, total_manure_CO2e_mtonnes_75, total_manure_CO2e_mtonnes_100, total_baseline_manure_CO2e_mtonnes])
Pipeline_transfer = (pipeline_CO2e_mtonnes_25, pipeline_CO2e_mtonnes_50, pipeline_CO2e_mtonnes_75, pipeline_CO2e_mtonnes_100,0)
FW = (fw_emissions_CO2e_44_mtonnes_25, fw_emissions_CO2e_44_mtonnes_50,fw_emissions_CO2e_44_mtonnes_75,fw_emissions_CO2e_44_mtonnes_100,fw_emissions_CO2e_44_mtonnes)
Upgrading = (total_upgrade_CO2e_mtonnes_25, total_upgrade_CO2e_mtonnes_50, total_upgrade_CO2e_mtonnes_75, total_upgrade_CO2e_mtonnes_100,0)
Transpo = (total_transpo_CO2e_mtonnes_25, total_transpo_CO2e_mtonnes_50, total_transpo_CO2e_mtonnes_75, total_transpo_CO2e_mtonnes_100,0)
Energy = (energy_savings_25, energy_savings_50, energy_savings_75, energy_savings_100, 0)

ax1.bar(x, Manure, color="r")
ax1.bar(x, Pipeline_transfer, bottom = Manure, color="g")
ax1.bar(x, FW, bottom = Manure+Pipeline_transfer, color="b")
ax1.bar(x, Upgrading, bottom=Manure+Pipeline_transfer+FW, color='y')
ax1.bar(x, Transpo, bottom=Manure+Pipeline_transfer+FW+Upgrading, color="c")
#ax1.bar(x, Energy, bottom=Manure+Pipeline_transfer+FW+Upgrading+Transpo, color="k")
ax1.bar(x, Energy, color="k")

plt.xlabel("Scenarios")
ax1.set_ylabel("CO$_{2}$e Emissions (Mtonnes)")
plt.legend(['Manure Management', 'Pipeline Transfer', 'Food Waste', 'Upgrading', 'Transportation', 'Energy'])
plt.title("CO$_{2}$e Emissions (Mtonnes) by Scenario")

ax1.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)

#plt.savefig('GHG Emissions')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Reading the [`Axes.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) docs may be helpful. You might consider using the `label` parameter when calling `ax1.bar`.